# Reading values from CFPropertyList

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

I am trying to read network interface configuration on macOS using the System Configuration framework with Swift. I am getting a `CFPropertyList` which actually is a `CFDictionary`. Each dictionary entry contains a `CFArray`. With `CFShow` I was able to verify that I got the expected data. What I am actually not able to do is to access the dictionary values. With `CFGetTypeId` I am not getting the same value as returned by `CFArrayGetTypeID()`.

Here is what I tried to get the IP address from the property list:

```
import SystemConfiguration

func readIP() {

    let cfName = "Demo" as CFString
    let dynamicStore = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, cfName, nil, nil)

    let key = "State:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv4" as CFString

    guard let plist: CFPropertyList = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, key) else {return}

    print("CFShow(plist):")
    CFShow(plist)

    print("Key: \(key):")
    print("Value: \(plist)")

    let typeIdPList = CFGetTypeID(plist)
    let typeIdDictionary = CFDictionaryGetTypeID()

    print("typeIdPList: \(typeIdPList)")
    print("typeIdDictionary: \(typeIdDictionary)")

    guard typeIdPList == typeIdDictionary else {return}

    let cfDict: CFDictionary = plist as! CFDictionary

    let rawPointerToKeyAddresses = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSCPropNetIPv4Addresses).toOpaque()
    var rawPointerToValue: UnsafeRawPointer?
    guard CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(cfDict, rawPointerToKeyAddresses, &rawPointerToValue) == true else {return}

    let anyRef: CFTypeRef = rawPointerToValue as CFTypeRef

    print("Value:")
    CFShow(anyRef)

    let typeIdValue = CFGetTypeID(anyRef)
    let typeIdArray = CFArrayGetTypeID()

    print("typeIdValue: \(typeIdValue)")
    print("typeIdArray: \(typeIdArray)")

    let cfArray: CFArray = anyRef as! CFArray
    let typeId = CFGetTypeID(cfArray)
    print("typeId: \(typeId)")

    let desc = CFCopyDescription(anyRef)
    let typeDesc = CFCopyTypeIDDescription(CFGetTypeID(anyRef))

    print("CFTypeRef description: \(desc!)")
    print("CFTypeRef type description: \(typeDesc!)")
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
CFShow(plist):
<CFBasicHash 0x610000069500 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3, entries =>
    0 : Addresses = <CFArray 0x610000069440 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x610000028980 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{contents = "192.168.139.24"}
)}
    1 : <CFString 0x610000044c20 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{contents = "BroadcastAddresses"} = <CFArray 0x610000069480 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x610000044c50 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{contents = "192.168.139.255"}
)}
    2 : <CFString 0x7fffc429d300 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{contents = "SubnetMasks"} = <CFArray 0x6100000694c0 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x6100000289a0 [0x7fffc4383da0]>{contents = "255.255.255.0"}
)}
}
Key: State:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv4:
Value: {
    Addresses =     (
        "192.168.139.24"
    );
    BroadcastAddresses =     (
        "192.168.139.255"
    );
    SubnetMasks =     (
        "255.255.255.0"
    );
}
typeIdPList: 18
typeIdDictionary: 18
Value:
0x0000610000069440
typeIdValue: 1
typeIdArray: 19
typeId: 1
CFTypeRef description: 0x0000610000069440
CFTypeRef type description: CFType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CFPropertyList` already supports subscripting, so there is no need to hassle with `CFDictionary` and raw pointers, you can simplify the code to

```
let cfName = "Demo" as CFString
let dynamicStore = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, cfName, nil, nil)
let key = "State:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv4" as CFString

guard let plist = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, key) else {return}
print(plist)

if let addresses = plist[kSCPropNetIPv4Addresses] as? [String] {
    print(addresses)
}
```

---

But if you are really curious how to make your `CFDictionary`/`CFArray`
based approach work: The problem  is that

```
let anyRef: CFTypeRef = rawPointerToValue as CFTypeRef
```

*wraps* the pointer value in to a `CFTypeRef` (aka `AnyObject`).
What you want is to *cast* the pointer:

```
let anyRef = unsafeBitCast(rawPointerToValue!, to: CFTypeRef.self)
guard CFGetTypeID(anyRef) == CFArrayGetTypeID() else { return }
let cfArray = anyRef as! CFArray
// ...
```

Another (equivalent) way of doing the pointer cast is

```
let anyRef = Unmanaged<CFTypeRef>.fromOpaque(rawPointerToValue!).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Comment: What I understood is that the bridging between `CFDictionary` and `NSDictionary` is "toll-free". Bridging to a Swift dictionary comes with some overhead, which might be an issue in some cases. Well probably not in the described use case, since there are only a view elements and updates are quite rare.

Comment: @Bokeh: It seems that a CFPropertyList already supports subscripting, so `guard let plist = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, key) else {return}` without the case works as well. – And I doubt that that cost of the Swift bridging is relevant. Compare the examples in https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 from the Apple Swift blog.

Comment: Actually I would like to understand how to do all the hassle with Core Foundation collections and raw pointers. I came across them several times and each time I am having problems. In other cases it might be necessary to use the CF interface directly because of performance reasons.

Comment: I googled a lot, but I haven't found your solution using Unmanaged<T>. These casts may result in runtime crashes, if the assumptions made about the types are wrong. Right? In my originally posted code I tried to avoid that by verifying the type id. For the dictionary I got the expected value of 18, but for the array I got 1 instead of the expected 19.

Comment: @Bokeh: I have now found the reason, see updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this. That was very helpful. Now I got both solutions working: Bridging to Swift types and staying in the Core Foundation domain.